# What is the command dd if=/dev/sdb do?

Tags: linux, bash, dd

I have formated my pendrive and it is in /dev/sdb. When I execute the command **dd if=/dev/sdb** command it keep printing some junk in console. My doubt is, when I format the pendrive and execute this command, it should not print anything. But why it is printing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formatting a drive does not (generally) zero out the data; it simply writes data  to certain locations on the drive such that your operating system believes that no space is allocated.

If you really want to zero out the data, you can run:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4096
```

This will write zeros to `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: Thank you @larsks Now I understand what is formatting really is :)

Comment: Not only does formatting the drive usually not zero it, if you take a blank disk at format it, you will find it now *DOES* have data on it--the partition table and filesystem information you just formatted onto it.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting a device does not get rid of previous data on the device.  All formatting will do is overwrite the filesystem data to make it marked as empty.  Any previous data not overwritten will still technically exist.  Also, dd will print out bytes of the raw data so even if you overwrite your drive with all 0s, dd would just return a whole bunch of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

dd will print to STDOUT (terminal window) unless you give it an output file.

Example:

```
dd if=dev/sdb of=backup.img
```

Terminology:

- dd: disk duplicator
- if: input file
- of: output file